# Echonest APi order retrieved genres

Tags: api, echonest

I'm calling the genre search method in the echonest API. When I make the call for "rock" (http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/genre/search?api_key=[API_KEY]&name=rock) I get a bunch of genres containing the string rock.

```
"genres": [134]
    0:  {
        "name": "african rock"
    }
    1:  {
        "name": "album rock"
    }
    2:  {
        "name": "alternative pop rock"
    }
    3:  {
        "name": "alternative rock"
    }
    4:  {
        "name": "alternative roots rock"
    }
    ...
}
```

I expected to get a list ordered based on the coincidence of the string but I can't seem to find a way to get the response in that order. Does anybody know how to do this?

I know I could process the response and modify the order but I am asking to get it done in the request.

Thank you in advance.